# Prove/Disprove that at least 3 colors are needed to color the vertices of G.

Tags: graph-theory

Here's the full question:

> Let G be a graph where every vertex has $degree\geq 3$. Prove or give a counterexample to the assertion that at least three colors are needed to color the vertices of G.

Been trying to figure this out for the past few hours now. I mean, we know that the largest $K_n$ graph contained within $G$ will be a $K_3$, so it follows then that we must have a chromatic number $\chi(G) \geq 3$. I feel, though, that this is stating what we need to be prove and is thus a very hollow argument.

If anyone could give a hand, would be much obliged.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try $K_{n,n}$ the complete bipartite graph on $n$ and $n$ vertices where $n \ge 3$.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend. I was trying to prove this, I realized, for a connected G--this was not stated anywhere in the given information. Beautiful, simple counterexample.